# increase the height of listview when new items are added

Tags: android, listview, height

I have been struggling to increase the height of listview when new items are added.

I wrap listview in scrollview, in order to scroll down listview items by scrollview scroll bar, not by nested scroll bar inside listview.

for doing this, listview height should be increased, it means scrollview scroll bar height also will be expanded.

Could you help me out of this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to have a listview inside a scrollview, it will cause conflict with the touch events.

Can you post your XML and code so we have a better understanding of what you're trying to achieve?